# Javascript method with type and default value

Tags: javascript, function, react-native

I have seen code of the form

```
functionName(isTrue: ?boolean = true) { //I came know that isTrue is parameter, of boolean type with true as default value
    if(isTrue) {
        //true Block
    }
    else {
       //false block
    }
}
```

I am new to Javascript, and using react-native from 3 months.
So I know that this is a kind of declaration of functions.

I want to know:

1. where is the documentation for such types of declarations.
2. if this kind of declaration is known by any name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing TypeScript with JavaScript.
The code snippet you have posted is in TypeScript.
TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript developed by Microsoft.

To understand more about how functions work in TypeScript refer this,
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

To understand and learn TypeScript, in general, I would suggest you start with the docs,
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/home

Once you are done with that take some course on some online platform like Udemy, Pluralsight etc...